# Memory Limit Reached while upgrading Magento 2.1.11 to 2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying t oupgrade Magento 2.1.11 to 2.1.12 but it keeps getting a memory limit fatal error. The error says

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 29 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

I have upgraded before using composer since version 2.1.9 and have not had an issue. This is the first time I am having this issue with an upgrade. The memory limit for PHP memory limit is 1024 MB . My host will not allow any more and my php.ini file does not affect the server (it is set to 2G). Is 2.1.12 a much higher memory user than the previous versions? Is there another way to upgrade without using Composer? The updater in Magento 2 has never worked. I have read that I can copy and past the updated files to the server, but that sounds like all kinds of problems waiting to happen. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i suggest you change hosting plans and look for a descend dedicated server or a VPS. They are not that expensive. I know workarounds exist but the limit is set for a reason.

Comment: @MagenX The question that you mentioned does not have a suitable answer, so I think that this is not a duplicate.